# How to use .noise .step and .meas in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I want to simulate that when I change the Cx in my circle, the difference of noise analyze result of gain.

[image]

It just prints only one gain value in the error log. How can get a result like:

```
step 1 gain1
step 2 gain2
```

Comment: AFAIK `.NOISE` measurements need `INTEG` or `RMS` or `AVG` because, even for a `.STEP` used with a `list` the `.MEAS` will report the measurement over the whole interval (see the note in the help: *LTspice > Dot Commands > .MEASURE*). OTOH, you can simply plot `gain` by making the waveform active and then use *Plot Sttings > Visible Traces*.

Comment: thank u , it works.